# How do I separate a list into two parts, the key and the values?

Tags: r, dictionary

I have a csv file that has a list of fruits and their monthly yields. Each fruit takes one row in the csv, and each month has its own column. I read it into R and separated each column with a comma.

The csv looks like this:

```
Apple, 312, 113, 177, 151, 31, 3
Orange, 613, 611, 687, 594, 431, 399
Pear, 23, 11, 7, 5, 3, 1 
Strawberry, 87, 91, 102, 111, 150, 165
Mango, 76, 76, 81, 92, 101, 97
```

I've used a function called readLines to read the csv into a List format like below:

```
df <- readLines('fruits.csv', sep = ",")
```

So in summary, now I want to separate the names of the fruits and their yields by giving the fruits the "key" attribute and the yields (numbers) the values, kind of like a dictionary.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: use `read.csv()` instead of `readLines()`

Comment: What is your desired output? (your dictionary comment is confusing me)

Comment: I want the name of the fruit to be separate from the numbers in terms of keys and values.

Comment: Yes, but do you want them as 2 elements of a list, 2 columns of a data frame, 2 lists...

Comment: 2 elements of a list sounds like what I'm going for actually, thank you. Something like Apples: 312, 113, 177 etc.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for some formatting rather than some data manipulation. Maybe you should read about R objects (lists, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

R's lists basically function like dictionaries. Something like this might work for you, where I first read in the CSV as a data frame, `split` the rows, and then iterate over the the resultant list, removing the fruit names and converting the remaining monthly values into a numeric vector:

```r
df <- read.csv("fruits.csv", header = F)
lapply(split(df, df$V1), function(x) as.numeric(x[-1]))
```

The above will return a list where the fruit names are the names of the list elements, and the monthly values are vectors of integers:

```r
$Apple
[1] 312 113 177 151  31   3

$Mango
[1]  76  76  81  92 101  97

$Orange
[1] 613 611 687 594 431 399

$Pear
[1] 23 11  7  5  3  1

$Strawberry
[1]  87  91 102 111 150 165
```

Comment: Oh ok cool, and what do I need to change in the lapply function if my values are in the form of dates (DD/MM/YYYY)?

Comment: @datacookies probably `as.Date`